# WP_Query with meta_query no results

Tags: meta-query

I have a custom post type and can get them using WP_Query with the following array:

```
$args = array(  
       'post_type' => 'projects',
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'posts_per_page' => 10,
   );
```

This works fine but now I have added a new field to the post type called 'featured_project' which is a checkbox with the value of 1, so to get only results with the checkbox checked I have added a meta_query, but with this meta_query I get no results and can't figure out why:

```
$args = array(  
       'post_type' => 'projects',
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'posts_per_page' => 10,
       'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'     => 'featured_project',
                'value'   => 1,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
        )
   );
```

I don't know why, I have googled this time and again and my code looks correct I think but with the meta_query addition I just get an empty set, could anyone please advise?
I'm using WordPress v5, php 7.1

I have just tried a new array format and changed the value of the 'featured_project' checkbox to 'featured', and still got no results.

```
   $args = array(  
       'post_type' => 'projects',
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'posts_per_page' => 10,
       'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'featured_project',
                'value'   => 'featured',
                'compare' => '=',
            )
        )
   );
```

And tried:

```
$args = array(  
       'post_type' => 'projects',
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'posts_per_page' => 10,
       'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'     => 'featured_project',
                'value'   => 'featured',
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
        )
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. Have you checked your stored meta data to confirm the value stored is 1? Also, have you tried comparing to a string value, eg '1' instead of 1? Just a stab in the dark, but worth a shot.

Assuming your stored values are correct, and seeing as the values can only ever be 1, you could try using:-

```
'compare' => 'LIKE'
```

LIKE usually works as a partial match, but in your case, it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Yes I finally realised that it was the way I had set the return value in the custom field, it's working now.